# Java Heap Size monitor solution

Tags: java, size, heap-memory, monitoring

I would like to monitor the used java heap size of a jboss service running on windows during serveral days. I first try to use perfmon from windows but I didn't get the value I expected. I can hook jvisualvm to this this service using jmx (server:port), I can also use jconsole or jmc (java mission control). Indeed I cannot use flight recording due to the jvm version.
With jcmd or jstat, I cannot see the process I'm interested in. As I'm new in Java, could someone suggest an application or script which would allow me to catpure those value and push them to a text file for example. I could code something in .Net as well if a library would exist.

Thanks

Comment: I try to use the psexec or to change the service user in order to get jcmd or jstat working, I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below java code records the Java Heap usage (2 mins once by default) to a text file. You can change the code as per your needs. Change the `private String jmxUrl = ...` as per your environment.

```
package com.heap.monitor;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.management.*;
import javax.management.remote.*;

public class HeapMonitor extends Thread {

private JMXServiceURL jmxService = null;
private JMXConnector jmxConnector = null;
protected MBeanServerConnection beanServerConn = null;
private long frequency = 2 * 60 * 1000L; // 2 mins only collects Heap metrics
private String jmxUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.8.252:12222/jmxrmi";
private String userName = "none";
private String passWord = "none";

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    HeapMonitor heapMonitor = new HeapMonitor();
    heapMonitor.join();
}

public HeapMonitor() {
    this.start();
}

public void run() {
    boolean flag = true;
    while(flag) {
        try {
            beanServerConn = connectToJVM(jmxUrl, userName, passWord);
            if(beanServerConn!=null) {
                MemoryMXBean mxbean = (MemoryMXBean) ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(beanServerConn, ManagementFactory.MEMORY_MXBEAN_NAME, MemoryMXBean.class);
                try
                {
                    MemoryUsage heapUsage = mxbean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
                    long used = heapUsage.getUsed();
                    long max = heapUsage.getMax();
                    long commited = heapUsage.getCommitted();
                    long init = heapUsage.getInit();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    Date date = new Date();
                    buffer.append(date).append(" - ");
                    buffer.append(init).append("   ").append(commited).append("   ").append(max).append("   ").append(used);
                    //System.out.println(buffer.toString());
                    appendStrToFile("heap.txt" , buffer.toString());
                }
                catch(Exception ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(frequency);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

protected MBeanServerConnection connectToJVM(String jvmURL, String user, String pass)
{
    beanServerConn = null ;  
    try
    {
        jmxService = new JMXServiceURL(jvmURL);
        Map environment = new HashMap();
        int jmxconnect_timeout = 30000;
        environment.put("jmx.remote.x.request.waiting.timeout", Long.toString(jmxconnect_timeout));


        if(user.equalsIgnoreCase("none")|| (pass.equalsIgnoreCase("none"))){
            try{
                jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxService,environment);
                beanServerConn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
            }
        }
        else
        {
            String [] credentials={user,pass};
            environment.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, credentials);
            try{
                jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxService,environment);
                beanServerConn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();

            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
            }
        }

        beanServerConn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();

        if(beanServerConn == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Connection to JVM is not established for jvmURL : " + jvmURL);
            closeJVMConn();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Connection to JVM is not established for jvmURL : " + jvmURL);
        closeJVMConn();
    }
    return beanServerConn;
}

public void closeJVMConn(){
    try{
        beanServerConn = null;
        if(jmxConnector != null)
            jmxConnector.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return;
    }
}

 public void appendStrToFile(String fileName, String str) { 
    try { 
        // Open given file in append mode. 
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true)); 
        out.write(str); 
        out.newLine();
        out.close(); 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) { 
        System.out.println("exception occoured" + e); 
    } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's excellent, I'm a .Net dev and I play with java very rarely. it does what I want

Comment: Thx for sharing! We're using a customized version of your class and discovered a thread leak that might also apply to your version. The request timeout does not work as expected and leaves time-outed threads open (verified with visualVM). We added a `jmxConnector.close()` statement at the end of the `try` block in `run` method to fix that leak.

Comment: @MaxM - Thanks for your update.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jconsole, you can view and capture the Heap/Non-Heap Memory usage (also CPU, Threads, etc). In the Jconsole a small popup windows appears when **Right Click Heap Memory Usage Graph** as shown in the screenshot. You can save the data in the .csv format for the selected time range.

[image: Jconsole Window]

Comment: Also you could try APM Tools like NewRelic- https://newrelic.com/ , AppDynamics- https://www.appdynamics.com/ , Stackify - https://stackify.com/  etc.

Comment: I was looking more like a background option or script which does not required to have an opened session as I would like to monitor it for long time. Jvisualvm would allow me to do some staff remotely but I might want to have this recording for about 2 weeks for example